# Why do commands like `vipw`, `visudo` exist, while a general editing with lock command does not exist?

Tags: configuration, editors

Commands like `vipw`, `visudo`, `vigr` open the configuration files with the default editor and set lock, so that the editing would be safe. Why do we have commands to edit these files specifically, while a more generic version of these commands that handle any file (e.g., "vi-with-lock") do not exist? What's the rationale here?

Comment: `vi` does warn you with `Found a swap file ...`

Comment: In all likelihood one of these commands popped up first and then the others were created as the first would already have some semantics and forcing those on others wouldn't make sense (e.g., `visudo` needs to check the syntax validity of the entirety of the `sudo` config, but `vipw` doesn't need to care about anything outside the file it was directed to edit). `vigr` is just an alias to `vipw`, IIRC.

Comment: I'm disagreeing with the close vote; while there's an argument that the answer may be opinion based there's some history there that might be beneficial.